# What ways are there to interrupt things like Leonas E

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that Leonas E can be interrupted by spells like Threshs E or Jannas Q and you see that quite often since they're more or less easy to hit. But how exactly does Leonas hitbox while she's in that form work?

Is she targetable by every skillshot or even by every non skillshot or autoattack? Could an almost unrealisticly well timed Blitz hook, Taric stun or even an autoattack with Udyrs bear stance interrupt her dash mid air? And if so: What kinds of CC or Hard CC could you use to interrupt her? (Amumus ult is somewhat strange for example)

Comment: Curious amumu's ult doesnt stop her right?

Comment: I actually asked because i wanna know if it's worth practicing for a madlife blitz hook to interrupt her ;P but yeah i'm curious in general about that spell^^ and amumus ult is neither a root nor a stun... it's really weird

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQz3fTYgrjM I'm hesitant to answer this question because I don't even know if riot knows all the interactions with zenith blade. Like last night I Zenith Bladed through a Malphite using unstoppable force and we just swapped places(I moved to his location when he cast the ult)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leona is targetable the whole travel time of Zenith Blade. The person hit by Zenith Blade is immobilized the duration of her travel time. Any skill that can stun/knockup a champion will end her travel and free the target from the immobilization. The hardest part is landing said stun in the duration of her travel time (After Zenith blade hits target, not while its still casting). Like you mentioned things like Blitzcrank's Rocket Grab, Amumu's Bandage Toss, Thresh's Flay, Ahri's charm, or even Leona's Solar Flare will stop her movement and free the immobilized target(Ex of how it looks.. [video skip to 3:30](http://youtube.com/watch?v=W2rprgM9Ouw)). This behavior is similar to Zac's Elastic Slingshot or other gap closers that can be interrupted.

The key thing to remember is that these interrupts need to be done **during the travel** not while Zenith Blade is still being cast. In this [video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=YQz3fTYgrjM) you'll notice the Zenith Blade is still casting when she is grabbed(Its going in a straight line from where she was). If blitz would have waited for her to start moving to the target it would have not had the same result. If done during the cast, the Zenith Blade will still leave the target immobilized until she arrives there or is killed, and when she arrives she will have whatever affect she may have obtained while casting (eg if you use Lulu's whimsey on her while Zenith Blade is casting she will still move but end up at the end location whimsey'd).

If you need to stop her before the cast finishes, then you need something that stops ranged attacks like Yasuo's WindWall.

I'm hesitant to just list out abilities because the list will need to be updated for each new champion, and also people may hit the skill at the beginning of the cast of Zenith Blade instead of after the skill lands and come back to tell me that it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I was under the impression that Leona is untargetable during the travel time, much like Maokai's twisted Advance.

Comment: Well it somehow makes sense... I mean you can't use a Janna Q to interrupt maokai or yi. Plus the abilities of those two are non skillshot and not a projectile.

Comment: @RavenDreamer i've seen madlife in ogn grab her on blitzcrank(cant find the vod) and its why thresh is good if they pick leona because he can flay back leo if she gets a Zenith blade off

Comment: Right, but during zenith blade, she's not targettable. Riot recently made a change that causes champions who go temporarily immune to CC (such as the slam on Vi's ult) get hit with the CC *after* the effect occurs. Might that be what you're seeing? Once Zenith blade lands, I've never seen Leona *not* teleport adjacent to the target.

Comment: Found this as an example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2rprgM9Ouw @ 3:30

Comment: Well this is a recent game of mine I recorded, and you can see that her e is definitely interruptable with thresh e http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLpUkf0LLuQ